# Selective nginx redirects without using 3xx

Tags: http, nginx, http-status-code-302

I have a situation where my application has two classes of servers (say A and B). Some requests get serviced by servers belonging to class A while others get serviced by servers in class B. A request comes to class A by default and then based on some business logic it either gets processed on A itself or needs to be redirected to B. I am using nginx as my reverse proxy. Is there a way I can leverage nginx to forward the request to B without using a 3xx redirect? The issue is that there are some legacy clients that are incapable of handling http redirects so returning a 3xx is not feasible. One option is for A to explicitly make a request to B through nginx but this involves an extra round trip. This would look like:
(client -> nginx -> A -> nginx -> B -> nginx -> A -> nginx -> client).

Is there an optimization I can do using nginx to do the following?
(client -> nginx -> A -> nginx -> B -> nginx -> client)

Note that there is one roundtrip less in the latter. A and B are collections of appservers.

Comment: Why not defining the proxy_upstream dynamically based on your choices (business logick)? Can you make an exampe what you are going to check to select if the request will be proxied to A or B? There are many options we have here but we need more information about your current config.

Comment: Can you post what you have right now?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you mean by dynamic but there are thousands of clients and there is no way to distinguish whether they go to A or B a'priori. Think of A as legacy servers and B as new servers. Over time some clients get migrated to use B but some are not for various reasons.